# DirectLineClient.Conversations.PostActivityAsync fails when from.id is lengthy

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

```
var GA_convId = "ABwppHGhvvx5Q0rxCX5jynq7_fGDwESH2O3P4xkgfnqbgQfw3IcYAdFkduAa3n3HhDgNCNrvhr0-2r4";

Activity act = new Activity() { ChannelId = Channels.Directline, From = new ChannelAccount() { Id = GA_convId, Name = GA_convId }, Text = msgtxt, TextFormat = "plain", Type = ActivityTypes.Message };

DirectLineClient client = new DirectLineClient(token);
ResourceResponse response = null;
response = await client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversationId, act );
```

in the previous code, PostActivityAsync will fail and no response is returned.
but if I set (from.id) to less lengthy string, let's say "mamhh", PostActivityAsync  will succeed and returns response.
I think this is a clear bug in the framework

How can I overcome such issue ???

Comment: Are you building the convoId yourself, or is it coming from somewhere?

Comment: It's comming to me  from third-party channel

Comment: First option -> Not Valid, Second option -> impacting performance,  Third option to be reconsidered

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximum length of 64 characters for `From.Id` and 256 characters for `From.Name`. This is less of a bug and more of an internal limit. However, there are a few workarounds you could consider:

1. Use a completely different string for the `From.Id`
2. Hash the `From.Id` into something smaller. You'd also have to keep a Dictionary of the hashes so you could map the hash back to the user name as needed within the bot
3. Use a different string for the `From.Id` and pass the `GA_convId` as needed through `Activity.ChannelData` so you can still use it within the bot.

Comment: I'll try your suggestions.. but I've noticed that when passing "DirectLine" as a channel .. the bot always sees it's "WebChat" .. very weird behavior.. any clues???

Comment: @user9942114 You can't set the channel; that gets set automatically for you. I'm not sure why it's setting it to WebChat. How are you retrieving your token?

Comment: How are you saying that "we can't set channel" ?  The Activity object has channel property and it could be set with no runtime issues !

Comment: @user9942114 Yes, it can be set your code. But as soon as it's sent, the channel consuming the activity will change it.